# Loading Youtube sample project in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, youtube-api

I want to look at the sample project youtube provided [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications) with it's API but Android Studio isn't loading properly. I think it's because it's designed for Eclipse. Can anybody guide me in what to do to get it to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried and imported the sample successfully.

You can just:

- Download the zip file and Unzip it.
- Use Android Studio go to `File --> New --> import project`.
- Select the `YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi-1-3` --> `sample` folder.
- If pop up any dialog just click yes and next.
- The project will import, and go build.grade in Module:app and change
  `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 22(which is new)
- Finally, put your APIKEY in `DeveloperKey.java`

Also I upload all code which you can refer [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/YoutubeSample-android).